# Opencv with Android- OCR

Tags: android, opencv

I want to do OCR for Sindhi, in an Android application, the idea is to let the person write on screen and then capture up the frame and then compare it with the images of the words pre saved in the mobile, and the image that matches up the most(using FLANN?) with the frame would have some text against it, and I just want to pronounce that text then. So please tell me if my approach is wrong, as I am new to Android and OpenCV both, or else tell me how do I start?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your aim, you want to compare the text written on the screen of the mobile with images where text is present, right?

I've done a bit of OCR on Android and I used OpenCV and Tesseract.

Tesseract is a real OCR engine but you need to have images that are as "clean" as possible. That's why you need OpenCV to clean them up before using Tesseract.

- OpenCv for Android : http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html
- Tesseract for Android : https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

So to give you the main lines of my workflow for a similar application :

1. Grab the text written by the user in a string or an array of strings.
2. Go fetch your pre-saved images
3. Process them through OpenCV, OpenCV is mainly used here to clean the images by getting rid of noise especially. You should try using a Glaussian Blur, then an Adaptive Threshold and a Bitwise-NOT (OCR engines deal better with black and white images that you obtain with the Bitwise-NOT)
4. After you get some clean images with OpenCV, process these images through Tesseract. That will give you a string for each image that contains the detected text on the images.
5. Compare your different strings gathered on Tesseract with the user's text by parsing each word to find out the text that matches the best.

For the audio part of your app, I'm not sure how to proceed, they must be some libraries out there that might help.

You must be aware that using all these libraries on Android is quite a struggle, you might have problems with the build of the project, follow well the different documentation that is provided on the official websites.